# Best and fastest way to compare two multi-word strings disregarding order of words?

Tags: mysql

What is the best and fastest way to compare two multi-word strings regardless of the order of the words?

I have a table of sayings and i want to eliminate similar terms. for example term: "`Mary Why Not`" should be the same as "`Why Not Mary`".

```
Table: Sayings
Field: Phrase
Values Row 1: "Mary Why Not" (matches Row 1)
Values Row 2: "Mary Not Why" (matches Row 1)
Values Row 3: "Mary Why"     (not a match)
```

Comment: Have you tried a MATCH AGAINST comparison?